# Why does skype not pick up my microphone?

Tags: audio, alsa, slackware, skype

I've got `skype` running (32 bit mode) on Slackware64 — the sound is fine but my mic is not able to be detected. KMIX shows that my mic is enabled, and I can hear myself when I test it.

Some notifications I get in Konsole when starting `skype` are below:

```
ALSA lib conf.c:4692:(snd_config_expand) Unknown parameters CARD=PCH
ALSA lib control.c:953:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default:CARD=PCH
```

EDIT -- 
Added screenshot.
[image]

Here is my ALSA mixer. If I turn the Front Mic all the way up, I can hear myself speaking through my output device. I have kept it down all the way so I don't hear myself.
[image]

Edit --

Another snapshot of AlsaMixer
[image]

Comment: Have you chosen your mic in skype's settings?

Comment: Yes, I've set it manually, and even left it on auto.

Comment: We need more info here, perhaps a screenshot of the skype audio settings page? Is any other application using the sound card? Can you get sound output in skype?

Comment: Added a screenshot of all of my Microphone options.

Comment: Please show the contents of your `~/.asoundrc` and `/etc/asound.conf` files.

Comment: @CL those files don't exist, that could be why

Comment: The error message "Unknown parameters" shows that the `default` device was redefined (incorrectly). Are the any configuration files in `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf.d/`?

Comment: It's working now, the issue was having the "Digital" all the way down.